# Null coalescing operator not working in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm currently migrating an application from EF5 to EF6 but ran into an issue with a unit test that runs this query:

```
return (from employeeWorkLocation in Retrieve()
                    where employeeWorkLocation.ClientId == clientId
                     && employeeWorkLocation.EmpUid == empUid
                     && employeeWorkLocation.EffectiveDate <= effectiveDate
                     && (!employeeWorkLocation.EffectiveEndDate.HasValue || employeeWorkLocation.EffectiveEndDate > effectiveDate)
                    join locationEntity in Context.WorkLocationEntities on employeeWorkLocation.WorkLocationUid equals locationEntity.WorkLocationUid into workLocations
                    from workLocation in workLocations.Where(wl => wl.Inactive == GenericYesNo.NO).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new EmployeeWorkLocation()
                    {
                        ClientId = employeeWorkLocation.ClientId,
                        EffectiveDate = employeeWorkLocation.EffectiveDate,
                        EffectiveEndDate = employeeWorkLocation.EffectiveEndDate,
                        EmployeeWorkLocationUid = employeeWorkLocation.EmployeeWorkLocationUid,
                        EmpUid = employeeWorkLocation.EmpUid,
                        MetaApplication = employeeWorkLocation.MetaApplication,
                        //MetaDateCreated = employeeWorkLocation.MetaDateCreated ?? DateTimeHelper.NowUnspecified,
                        MetaCreatedBy = employeeWorkLocation.MetaCreatedBy,
                        //MetaDateUpdated = employeeWorkLocation.MetaDateUpdated ?? DateTimeHelper.NowUnspecified,
                        MetaUpdatedBy = employeeWorkLocation.MetaUpdatedBy,
                        WorkLocationUid = employeeWorkLocation.WorkLocationUid,
                        HrLocationUid = workLocation.HRPLocationUid
                    }).OrderByDescending(e => e.EffectiveDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

For some reason if I remove the comments above I get this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error
>   occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details. ---> System.ArgumentException: Argument types
>   do not match

I tried changing those lines to the long version (ternary operator) but still no luck. I get same error:

> MetaDateCreated = employeeWorkLocation.MetaDateCreated != null ?
>   employeeWorkLocation.MetaDateCreated.Value :
>   DateTimeHelper.NowUnspecified,

`employeeWorkLocation.MetaDateCreated` and `employeeWorkLocation.MetaDateUpdated` are both of nullable `Datetime?` type

`DateTimeHelper.NowUnspecified` is of `Datetime` non-nullable type. Same as `MetaDateCreated` and `MetaDateUpdated`

Any ideas? This was working fine with Entity Framework 5

**Update:** Here is the definition for `DateTimeHelper.NowUnspecified`:

```
public static DateTime NowUnspecified
{
    get
    {
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    }
}
```

If I replace `DateTimeHelper.NowUnspecified` with `DateTimeHelper.Now` as suggested in the comments my test passes...

**Update2:** After isolating the issue using LinqPad I realized that Entity Framework 6 was handling the query correctly. The problem is with Effort.EF6 library which is throwing the exception

Thanks,

Comment: What is `DateTimeHelper.NowUnspecified`?

Comment: @IvanStoev it's of `DateTime` type. Non-nullable. I'll add that to the description

Comment: Try `DateTime.Now` instead and see if it helps.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` works!!, why could the other helper method not work? I put the definition in my question..

Comment: @AdolfoPerez both of them are DateTime structs, because DateTime is a struct

Comment: In general EF does not like custom methods. Another thing you could try is moving it to variable outside of the query, e.g. `var defaultDate = DateTimeHelper.NowUnspecified;` and use that variable inside.

Comment: @pquest but why is `DateTime.Now` working but `DateTime.NowUnspecified` isn't?

Comment: @AdolfoPerez EF likely could not support the DateTime.SpecifyKind method since there really is no equivalent in sql. It complied fine because it is syntactically correct, but when EF tried to convert the linq into a sql query it had no idea what to do there. When you need to use specialized logic like that on the results, it is better to run the query first, and then apply the logic on the local machine.

Comment: Although I've tried something similar to your query and it works (EF6.1.3, SqlServer).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that EF does not know how to translate your property to sql. If you really need to use that property (or run into situations like this in the future), you can do so by forcing EF to execute the query prior to that portion of the logic and apply it locally:

```
return (from employeeWorkLocation in Retrieve()
                    where employeeWorkLocation.ClientId == clientId
                     && employeeWorkLocation.EmpUid == empUid
                     && employeeWorkLocation.EffectiveDate <= effectiveDate
                     && (!employeeWorkLocation.EffectiveEndDate.HasValue || employeeWorkLocation.EffectiveEndDate > effectiveDate)
                    join locationEntity in Context.WorkLocationEntities on employeeWorkLocation.WorkLocationUid equals locationEntity.WorkLocationUid into workLocations
                    from workLocation in workLocations.Where(wl => wl.Inactive == GenericYesNo.NO).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new{employeeWorkLocation, workLocation})
                    .ToArray() //this will cause EF to run the query
                    //Everything below this runs in the .NET code 
                    //rather than on sql server
                    .Select(wl => new EmployeeWorkLocation()
                    {
                        ClientId = wl.employeeWorkLocation.ClientId,
                        EffectiveDate = wl.employeeWorkLocation.EffectiveDate,
                        EffectiveEndDate = wl.employeeWorkLocation.EffectiveEndDate,
                        EmployeeWorkLocationUid = wl.employeeWorkLocation.EmployeeWorkLocationUid,
                        EmpUid = wl.employeeWorkLocation.EmpUid,
                        MetaApplication = wl.employeeWorkLocation.MetaApplication,
                        MetaDateCreated = wl.employeeWorkLocation.MetaDateCreated ?? DateTimeHelper.NowUnspecified,
                        MetaCreatedBy = wl.employeeWorkLocation.MetaCreatedBy,
                        MetaDateUpdated = wl.employeeWorkLocation.MetaDateUpdated ?? DateTimeHelper.NowUnspecified,
                        MetaUpdatedBy = employeeWorkLocation.MetaUpdatedBy,
                        WorkLocationUid = wl.employeeWorkLocation.WorkLocationUid,
                        HrLocationUid = wl.workLocation?.HRPLocationUid
                    }).OrderByDescending(e => e.EffectiveDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You can move the `.OrderByDescending(...)` to before the `.ToArray()` call. And you can `.AsEnumerable()` instead of `.ToArray()`, it prevents materializing the collection.

Comment: I think you can save reading the whole query-results by doing this: `(from select new {}).OrderBy().FirstOrDefault()` and then do the projection on the single record that you have left.